# C projet work as well in Linux but not working on Windows

Tags: c, linux, macos

I built a C projet on Linux and when i tried to execute it on windows it didn't work. Can u help me with finding a solution ?.
[Error message in my Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQUaK.png)

when i tried to debug i found a problem here, it stuck in this while loop
[image]

in the main we call the function init_dicContexte()

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "liste_mots.h"
#include "liste_freq.h"
#include "dict_contexte.h"


int main(void) {

    char* texte;

    FILE* fichier;
    if ((fichier = fopen("Jane_Austen_Emma2.txt", "r"))==NULL)
        raler("fopen");

    if(fseek( fichier , 0L , SEEK_END))
        raler("fseek");
    long taille_fichier = ftell(fichier);
    rewind(fichier);

    texte = calloc(1, taille_fichier+1);
    if (texte == NULL){
        fclose(fichier);
        raler("calloc");
    }

    if(fread(texte, taille_fichier, 1, fichier)!=1){
        fclose(fichier);
        free(texte);
        raler("fread");
    }

    dictContexte mon_dict = init_dictContexte(texte);

    afficher_dict(mon_dict);

    genererTexte(mon_dict, 15);

    free(texte);
    return 0;
}
```

init_dictContext() is like that

```
dictContexte init_dictContexte(char* t) {

    int i = 0;

    listeFreq liste_freq = frequencesDe(t);
    _listeFreq freq_cour = liste_freq.liste;

    // allocation de l'espace mémoire
    dictContexte nouv_dict = malloc(sizeof(struct a_dictContexte));
    dictContexte contexte_cour = nouv_dict;

    printf("Creation du dictionnaire de contexte..\n");

    while (freq_cour->freq_suivante!=NULL && k <2) {

        i++;

        contexte_cour->contexte = contexte(t, freq_cour->mot);
        strcpy(contexte_cour->mot, freq_cour->mot);

        dictContexte nouv_contexte = malloc(sizeof(struct a_dictContexte));
        strcpy(nouv_contexte->mot, "\0");
        contexte_cour->suivant = nouv_contexte;

        // ajout d'un contexte
        contexte_cour = nouv_contexte;
        freq_cour = freq_cour->freq_suivante;
    }

    nouv_dict->taille = i;

    detruit_liste_freq(liste_freq.liste);
    return nouv_dict;
}
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share your code as formatted text, not a screenshot

Comment: Please don't show pictures of text. Show the text itself (including the error message).

Comment: When you're asking for help, please don't post screenshots or photographs. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Answer (score 1):

The error: `pointer being free'd was not allocated` is an example of heap corruption.

Heap corruption bugs are notorious in that the program *appears* to work, and then suddenly crashes when given a different input, or moved to a different system.

If your friend were to build the program on Linux using address sanitizer (`gcc -fsanitize=address ...`), he would discover that the bug is present on Linux as well.

To tell you where the actual bug is, we'd need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

But you can help yourself: run the executable under debugger, set a breakpoint on `malloc_error_break` (as the error message tells you), use `where` command and you will find out exactly where the error is detected.

P.S. It looks like the pointer being `free()` has not been initialized (i.e. contains "random" garbage).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a linked list. Typically, the "next" member of the last node in the list should be set to `NULL` so you can know where the list ends. I can't see you are doing that.

Sometimes it may happen that the memory returned by `malloc` is initialized to zero. When this happen, the "next" member will have the value `NULL` and the program will have the appearance of working. But this is purely by chance, and you cannot rely on that.